# Angular 2 quickstart why do we need System.import in index.html

Tags: angular, systemjs

I was testing my version of the QuickStart tutorial from Angular 2 where I use a bundle js file. The index.html is like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular 2 QuickStart Deploy</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="lib/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/Reflect.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/system.src.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('app').catch(function(err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>
  <!-- 2. Display the application -->
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    <!-- application bundle -->
    <script src="app/bundle.app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So when I execute this, my Hello world message is displayed in the screen, but there's an error in the console `syntax error: unexpected token <`

After much testing, I realize that if I remove the following line from the index.html file, everything works and no error message is displayed.
`System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });`

So... I thought that this line was the entry point for the application, main file with the bootstrap, but apparently it's not needed. Am I missing something?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

This are 2 screenshots of the result with and without the System.import
In both cases it seems it's working, with no errors when System.import is not in the index.html and with errors otherwise. Also, when System.import is in the index it seems it's trying to load the app module and somehow it's giving an error. I can´t really understand why it happens.

[image]
[image]

Also, my systemjs.config.js regarding app:

```
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'app',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };
...
```

I created the bundle in Gulp using systemjs-builder

```
gulp.task('bundle:app', () => {
  builder.buildStatic('app/*.js', 'web/app/bundle.app.js')
  .then(function() {
    console.log('Build complete');
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log('error ' + err);
  })
})
```

Comment: `System.import` *is* the entry point. The fact that it tries to resolve `app` module from `.../app` path and loads html from there suggests that `app` wasn't defined properly in `systemjs.config.js`.

Comment: I updated my question with part of my system.config.js. The structure in my deploy folder is ./web/app for my bundle.app.js and index.html in /web.

Comment: Then it is supposed to load `app/main.js`, so it's not clear why it loads just `app`. The whole thing is unstable, and package versions matter. A plunker [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would help to resolve this. I see that you've updated index.html with real code. This explains why it works without `System.import`. If you have bundled script, you don't need `System.import`. It's either one or another.

Comment: Yes, I had copied the index.html from a previous version without the bundle. I didn´t know that with the bundle you don´t need to System.import an initial module. Why is that? I didn´t specify any initial module to load when I created my bundle.

Comment: The question cannot get a quality answer if it doesn't contain the necessary details. It's not clear how `bundle.app.js` is built and what it contains. If it works as entry point and contains the same `main.js` as the one that is supposed to be loaded by `System.import`, another entry point is not necessary (and likely harmful).

Comment: Thanks, @estus; I edited again my question with the code to build the bundle with systemjs-builder; as you see, quite simple. The app itself is the quickstarter from angular page, so really simple, main.ts and app.component.ts, both inside source folder /app

Comment: The reference to quickstart is misleading. [This page](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/quickstart.html) contains no information on `systemjs-builder` setup. And from your code it is not evident that `systemjs-builder` uses the same ` systemjs.config.js` as `System.import`. But if it does, you're trying to do the same work twice - load both built script with `bundle.app.js` and unbuilt script with `System.import('app')`. `System.import('app')` is *necessary* in original quickstart. And `System.import('app')` is *unwanted* in your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need the `System.import` to bootstrap and run your application.

It can't run without it, and if it does, you might have a cashed version in your browser.

The error:

```
syntax error: unexpected token <
```

is usually an indication that some of the script files didn't get loaded correctly, or you have an error that prevented your app compiled JS files from being loaded.

Without more information on your error and the output in the console, it's hard to tell what exactly is the problem.

Comment: thanks, @Boyan. I tried cleaning memory cache in my browser and I also tried in other browsers, but it's working without the System.import (??). I updated my question to provide more info in case it helps.

Comment: I see now. Like @estus suggested, you don't need both the system.import and the bundle.js file. Bundling is used to combine all the scripts and serve everything from a single script. That is usually done when you are serving the app in production. Using System.Import is the recommended way to do it while you are developing.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than:

```
System.import('app').catch(function(err) { console.error(err); });
```

On my personal experience, I think it's better to use:

```
System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
```